# Understanding the solution of wave equation in 2 dimension?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

In Walter Strauss, the author derives the solution of wave equation in 3 dimension and observes the following point

- The solution involves and integration over the surface of sphere (Krichoff formula) which implies that only surface affect the solution not the points inside it (and is called Huygen's principle).

In the next section he attempts to prove the solution in 2 dimension by ignoring the third coordinate i.e. $z$-coordinate. The result is we manage to simplify the surface integral into a regular integral (i.e. having dxdy instead of dS) and limits changes from the surface of a sphere to a disk. Due to this the author claimed that Huygen's principle is violated in the 2 dimension case because the solution is influenced by the points inside the disk.

One can see the acutall calculation here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Scalar_wave_equation_in_general_dimension_and_Kirchhoff's_formulae

Now here is my doubt.

In the two dimension case, there is a step where we change the surface integral into double integral (see the section Scalar wave equation in two space dimensions in the above link). My doubt is why I can't do the same  step in the 3 dimension case. This step for me (uptill now) doesn't seem to utilize the fact that solution is not dependent of $z$-variable.

Comment: If you want to violate Huygen in dimension three with this method, you need to have a similar type of formula for dimension 4, so that you can drop down one dimension and get a 'disk'.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I think you misunderstood my question. I have reedited the post.

Comment: If I have misunderstood your question, then I still don't understand your edit. You mean, we can use this to show that the 3D solution is given by an integral over a disk? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @CalvinKhor yes I feel that 3D solution can be further simplified to a disk. This would conclude that Huygens principle is not valid in 3D

Comment: The Huygens principle demonstrates that the 2D solution depends on a certain 2D surface. The fact that the general 3D solution can be written as an integral over a 2D surface(sphere or disk or other coordinates) is not in violation of Huygens.